# Can "zipping" corrupt .dll file?

Tags: asp.net, dll, telerik, zip

Recently I had very weird situation. 
I was trying to publish my website on a server so I prepared a build on my local machine, zipped it and then deployed on a server box. 

I was really amused when I realised that after server publish a (Telerik).dll that was responsible for UI stopped working (It was okay while debug on localhost). 

After few retries I came into situation where when I publish unzipped .dll it works! When I zip them and then uncompress they don't seem to work.
Did anyone had similar problems?

Comment: When you say "they don't seem to work", what kind of error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Controls just don't show up in UI (but content is in the right place)